# On or in the delivery note?

Tags: word-choice

Which one is correct:
"this information must be stated on the delivery note?" or 
"this information must be stated in the delivey note?"?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

They're more-or-less interchangeable, though I'd generally use "on" as you'd usually write on a single piece of paper (as delivery notes usually are) rather than in one. Writing in something is more commonly used if there are multiple pages bound together, as in a notebook or journal.

Answer (score 2):

They are almost identical.

"... **on** the delivery note" means that the information is written on the piece of paper called the *delivery note*. Here, *note* refers to the piece of paper.

"... **in** the delivery note" means that the information forms part of the text of the *delivery note*. Here, *note* refers to the text itself.

In practice, both versions mean that the information must be presented along with the other delivery information.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say either one is fine. However, "in the delivery note" sounds a tad bit more business like, and the wording of the rest of the text sounds kind of formal because of the word "stated". "on the delivery note" sounds a little like they would just take a pen and write it "on" the note. "in the delivery note" sounds like they would type it into the document that comes with the delivery. (I'm coming at this with an American perspective. It might sound different to a Brit.